# Update the database from SqlDataAdapter using UpdateParameters

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a problem and I need help, I have a gridview binding from `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOpened" HeaderText="DateOpened" 
            SortExpression="DateOpened" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rName" HeaderText="rName" SortExpression="rName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfArrival" HeaderText="DateOfArrival" 
            SortExpression="DateOfArrival"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
            SortExpression="Quantity"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sName" HeaderText="sName" SortExpression="sName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="osName" SortExpression="osName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="OrderStatusDDL">
                <asp:ListItem>הוזמן</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>מתעכב</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>התקבל</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> 
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("osName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

`SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup9_test1ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="spGetOrdersListForProject" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="spUpdateOrderStatus" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ProjectIDHolder" DefaultValue="" 
            Name="ProjectID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>

    <UpdateParameters>
       <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ProjectIDHolder" DefaultValue="" 
               Name="@projectid" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
       <asp:ControlParameter Name="@osID"  PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32"  
               ControlID="OrderStatusDDL" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I want to edit the `osName` column and when I press the `Edit` button and try to choose a different value from the dropdownlist, I want to update the `osId` (`int`) in the database but I get this error:

> Could not find control 'OrderStatusDDL' in ControlParameter '@osID'.

Answer (score 0):

Is the GridView on a page that utilizes a MasterPage?  If so, you need to prefix the control with the ID of the `ContentPlaceHolder`.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="@osID"  PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32"
ControlID="ContentPlaceholderID$OrderStatusDDL" />
```

Comment: Look at the rendered HTML and see what the ID of the control is.

Comment: the control id is :ContentPlaceHolder3_GridView1_OrderStatusDDL_0" and when i try to use that id the error is "Could not find control 'ContentPlaceHolder3_GridView1_OrderStatusDDL_0' in ControlParameter '@projectid'."

Comment: The error message is now saying `@projectid` instead of `@osID`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to pass the text value of OrderStatusDDL.SelectedValue into an int field.  Try changing the Type to string and see if that helps.

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="@osID"  PropertyName="Text" Type="String" ControlID="OrderStatusDDL" />
```

I don't know if this will help, but it might be a good place to start.